# command script returns "Too many ('s."

Tags: bash

The following script I was building on a RHEL 5 and it worked fine. However now I am testing on various RHEL6 and Ubuntu and the message is consistent "Too many ('s.". Any thoughts as to what is going on. This is the script that I am working on

```
$ echo "HOST,UserName,IsDiabled,PassLastSet" > fileIWantToWriteTo;
$ ( echo "foreach user ( `cut -d':' -f'1' /etc/passwd` )";
    echo "sudo passwd -S "\$"user" ; echo "end"
  ) | csh | 
  sed 's/ /,/g' | cut -f1-3 -d',' | 
  sed 's/LK/DISABLED/' | 
  sed 's/PS/ENABLED/' | 
  awk 'BEGIN{"hostname" | getline hstnm ; }{print hstnm "," $0}' \
    >> fileIWantToWriteTo
```

Now I am testing this on various Linux OS, and I am getting the following output message

```
# ( echo "foreach user ( `cut -d':' -f'1' /etc/passwd` )"
echo "sudo passwd -S "\$"user" ; echo "end" ) | 
csh | 
sed 's/ /,/g' | 
cut -f1-3 -d',' | 
sed 's/LK/DISABLED/' | 
sed 's/PS/ENABLED/' | 
awk 'BEGIN{"hostname" | getline hstnm ; }; {print hstnm "," $0}'
Too many ('s.
```

However when I was testing , I had success .

```
# ( echo "foreach user ( `cut -d':' -f'1' /etc/passwd` )"
echo "sudo passwd -S "\$"user" ; echo "end" ) | 
csh | 
sed 's/ /,/g' | 
cut -f1-3 -d',' | 
sed 's/LK/DISABLED/' | 
sed 's/PS/ENABLED/' | 
awk 'BEGIN{"hostname" | getline hstnm ; }; {print hstnm "," $0}'
tophostd,root,ENABLED,2015-08-31 tophostd,bin,DISABLED,2013-08-19
```

Comment: Your code is just about illegible. Please split it into lines, indent it correctly, and format it as code using the "{}" link.

Comment: @DavidCRanking Kudos for that edit. I started and gave up ;)

Comment: The practice of piping the output of one poorly understood command to another poorly understood command is discouraged. If you use `awk` anyway, you can dispense with `cut` and `sed`. And if this is a `bash` issue, why are you piping stuff to `csh`?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that when you tested that command line, you only had one user-id in the list. The reasoning behind that guess follows a small digression.

#### Simplifying the script

Using bash to create a compound command to send to `csh` strikes me as either wilful obfuscation or bizarre overthinking. Instead of the not-working

```
( echo "foreach user ( `cut -d':' -f'1' /etc/passwd` )"
  echo "sudo passwd -S "\$"user" ; echo "end"
) | csh |
# ...
```

You could just do:

```
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do
  sudo passwd -S $user
done
```

No need for csh at all, and it's all a lot easier to read, too. Plus it works. (It does assume that no username includes whitespace or glob characters.)

Even simpler would be

```
sudo passwd -Sa
```

which produces status information on all accounts. (Assuming your `passwd` implements that option.)

Also:

```
sed 's/ /,/g' | cut -d, -f1-3
```

would probably be more readable as

```
cut -f1-3 --output-delimiter=,
```

and the two edits

```
sed 's/LK/DISABLED/' | sed 's/PS/ENABLED/'
```

can be put into a single command:

```
sed 's/LK/DISABLED/;s/PS/ENABLED/'
```

You could also insert the prefix using sed

```
hostname=$(hostname)
sed "s/^/$hostname,/;s/LK/DISABLED/;s/PS/ENABLED/"
```

so that the final result would be

```
hostname=$(hostname)
sudo passwd -Sa |
cut -d' ' --output-delimiter=, -f1-3 |
sed "s/^/$hostname,/;s/LK/DISABLED/;s/PS/ENABLED/"
```

which seems to me a lot more straightforward. Alternatively, you could use `awk` instead of `cut`+`sed`:

```
sudo passwd -Sa |
awk -v hostname="$(hostname)" \
  '{ sub(/LK/, "DISABLED", $2);
     sub(/PS/, "ENABLED", $2);
     printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", hostname, $1, $2, $3;
   }'
```

#### But returning to the question

Anyway, the reason your script fails:

`csh` is *very* specific about command formats. It does not tolerate newlines in unexpected places. The syntax of a foreach statement is precisely:

```
foreach <var> ( <list> )
  <commands>
end
```

*There cannot be newlines in the `<list>`* (unless you escape them with a backslash).

Now, when you ask bash to execute a command, using `$(command [args...])` (or the deprecated backtick notation `` `command [args...]` ``, which you should really stop using): (emphasis added)

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, *with any trailing newlines deleted.*

So if the command returns a single line, there will be a single trailing newline and it will be deleted:

```
$ echo "foreach i ( $(seq 1) )"
foreach i ( 1 )
```

But if there is more than one line, you'll end up with internal newlines:

```
$ echo "foreach i ( $(seq 1 2) )"
foreach i ( 1
2 )
```

The first of those will work fine. But if you feed the second one into `csh`, it will complain with the slightly mysterious message "Too many ('s.".

You could eliminate the internal newlines by word-splitting the line, which would mean not using quotes. (You still need to quote the parentheses, though.)

```
$ echo foreach i \( $(seq 1 2) \)
foreach i ( 1 2 )
```

You need to be sure that there are no glob metacharacters in the substitution, though, because unquoted substitutions will also expand globs. On the whole, I'd stick with the approaches outlined in the first part of this answer, and avoid the difficulties of assembling commands to pass to another shell.